# Activecell not in Array

Tags: vba

**Having difficulty comparing my activecell against a predefined array.**

After importing data from another source I want to trim out the columns I don't need

I've trued the array as both undefined, string and variant
And tried `activecell / activecell.value <> NeededColumns`
No joy :(

```
 Sub Trim()        
    Dim NeededColumns As Variant
        NeededColumns = Array("APPLICATION NUMBER", "DATE", "BRAND", "CHANNEL", "SCHEME")


    Range("A1").Select
    Do Until ActiveCell = ""
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ActiveCell.Value, NeededColumns, 0) = 0 Then
            ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Delete
        Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with ?

Comment: I get to the If statement and then VBA goes to Debug 
'Run-time error '1004'
Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class'

Comment: @JBear, you have set the ActiveCell before going into the loop. Inside the loop you have not set the ActiveCell again, if it gets deleted, what is the next ActiveCell?

Comment: I've edited Activecell.EntireRow.Delete to Activecell.EntireColumn.Delete

Activecell starts as A1 outside the loop.
If the column is deleted it would remain as A1 in what was B1 before
Or offset to the next column

Comment: If it helps to give more backing... I'm importing a dataset with 100 columns. I only need around 20 and the headers in row 1 are the only indicators of what I want / don't want... I'm attempting this method but I'm open to suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have fallen victim to the odd behavior of `WorksheetFunction.Match` when it cannot find a match.  Instead of returning the error, it throws a run time error which gums up the works.

Since the premise of this question is searching for whether or not something is in a list, you are nearly guaranteed to see this issue since you expect to have some items that will not show up.  In the formula version of `MATCH` you would get `#N/A` when it does not find a match.  Here, you get a runtime error.  There are two solutions to this:

1. Use the `Application.Match` version of the function instead of `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match`.  Unfortunately, Intellisense will not help you here, but it is a valid function.  It has the key difference that it will **return** an error instead of throwing a runtime error.  You can then check this error using `IsError` like your original idea.
2. Use an `On Error Goto XXX` to route the error to somewhere instead of the `If`.  You can generally assume that an error here means you did not find an entry, and then work around it that way.

Given these two choices, I strongly recommend you go with option 1.  That code would look something like:

```
Sub Trim()
    Dim NeededColumns As Variant
    NeededColumns = Array("APPLICATION NUMBER", "DATE", "BRAND", "CHANNEL", "SCHEME")


    Range("A1").Select
    Do Until ActiveCell = ""
        If IsError(Application.Match(ActiveCell.Value, NeededColumns, 0)) Then
            ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Delete
        Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

I have traded your `=0` condition for a check on `IsError(Application.Match(...))` this will return `True` if the column is not found.

Additional reading: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/09/24/the-worksheetfunction-method/